# Field of convergence, prove it's open?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

For the following power series $$ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} \bigg( 1 + \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \bigg)^{ n^2}  \frac{(2x+1)^n}{n} $$ I proved that the radius of convergence is $r= \frac{1-e}{2 \ e} $.
How may I prove that the interval of convergence is open and not closed?

Comment: Check the convergence on boundary.

Comment: Field of convergence is also not the correct terminology; I think you mean interval of convergence.

Comment: @user251257 I know that's what I need to do, But I couldn't move on... it gets really hard

Comment: @Carlo corrected that, thanks

Comment: Just substitute $x$ by $\pm R$ and check every convergence theorem you know (there should not be many).